# About database design: How should I classify some date information?

Tags: database

New to database and confused by some concept so I come to seek help.
Wanna to design a database about package delivery company, which needs to  keep track of packages.
There are a few of entities: delivery company, warehouse, conveyance(like plane), shipper, and receiver. The company need to know the where and when package is at any time, and check the situation of the warehouse or plane, like what they've delivered last month.

Tried to add a current time column to the package entity but if so it can't be tracked at any time, and the company can't check the concrete situation of the warehouse or conveyance.

Thought of adding a time entity including columns: **time**, ID of package, posistion. But I wonder if it's reasonable since the entities I've seen (like students, teachers and workers) are kinda different from this and it's hard to describe in the E-R diagram. Is this thought reasonable or is there any better advice?

Not a English native speaker if my expression is confusing you may ask, thank you. :)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. I am afraid you are asking too many questions in your post. You need to focus on just one, and provide information on what you have tried so far (with code examples). Doing this will help ensure you get good quality replies.

Comment: thank you for reminding! It's my first time to use this so I will be careful next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this schema as a skeleton. It should work for you. On every update on the package table you should insert a row to package_history with updated values (maybe using a trigger).

You can reach not just the current place and time information but also the whole history of a package by querying the `package_history` table.

Maybe you can add a new table for city/province information, it's up to you.

I haven't specified the datatypes but I think it's understandable.

```
package
-------
id PK
package_name
from
to
place_id FK
status_id FK

place
------
id PK
city
place_name (delivery company, warehouse, conveyance(like plane), shipper, and receiver)

status
-----
id PK
status_name (waiting, in process, ready to deliver etc...)

package_history
-------------
id PK
package_id FK
place_id FK
status_id FK
status_datetime
additional_notes
```